# How to get JSON data from Rest API by PHP Curl?

Tags: php, api, rest, php-curl

I have a Rest api which I can access by this url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/thesis/?format=json". Now I want to get the JSON data from it. For connecting to the api I tried to use PHP-Curl as below. But I get NULL! (This is the first time I'm doing php any help will be great!)

```
<?php
$service_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/thesis/?format=json";
//initialize a curl session
$curl = curl_init();
//set options for the transfer
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
//execute the session
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
//finish off the session
curl_close($curl);
$curl_jason = var_dump(json_decode($curl_response, true));
print_r($curl_jason);
echo $curl_jason;
?>
```

Comment: what method you are using POST or GET

Comment: `var_dump($curl_response)` before trying to json_decode it. You should have a look at [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: I'm sure curl is running (because I get the curl field when I run the phpinfo() )

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use `GET` method of `curl` like this

```
$service_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/thesis/?format=json";
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//execute the session
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
//finish off the session
curl_close($curl);
$curl_jason = json_decode($curl_response, true);
print_r($curl_jason);
```

Comment: I'm using GET method and, tried your version also but I still get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below mentioned code snippet to fetch data from a REST API using **PHP curl**

```
 <?php
    function _isCurl(){
        return function_exists('curl_version');
    }    
    if (_iscurl()){
        //curl is enabled
        $url = "http://testDomainName/restAPI.php?id=123&amt=100&jsonp=?";    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($output);
       // Curl operations finished            
    }
    else{
        echo "CURL is disabled";
    }
    ?>
```